# Reading from a confidential file

Tags: c#, winforms, security, deployment

(See what I did there?)

I am developing a WinForms application which needs to retrieve information from a file which contains sensitive information. The information retrieved is used to perform some complex calculations, but it includes things like salaries of certain pay bands for employees of a large company. The WinForms application will eventually need to be deployed to members of that company, but I need to make sure that I do not reveal the contents of this file to them.

The file itself is a JSON file, and is currently stored locally within the Visual Studio project file structure.

If I was to "Publish" this application through Visual Studio's Build menu, and release it through a web link, would people be able to open up this JSON file and view it? If so, is there some way this can be avoided? I have considered storing the file online and accessing it via HTTP request, however I don't really know much about that so could do with some advice.

Cheers,
Josh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I was to "Publish" this application through Visual Studio's Build menu, and release it through a web link, would people be able to open up this JSON file and view it?

Yes.

> If so, is there some way this can be avoided?

Only by not publishing the file.

You should look into storing this information in a database that can only be accessed through an authorised account via HTTPS. I'd recommend using WCF as it will integrate well with C# and WinForms. The best approach would be to perform the calculations on the server side (either in the WCF service itself or as stored procedures in the database). Thus you only need to gather the inputs on the client, pass these back to the server and then display the result.

You can also do things like logging all attempts (successful or not) to access this data so you have a complete audit trail. You can also expose your WCF service to other clients if necessary.

Comment: I guess the other way I could do this is to take the inputs from the WinForm, send them via HTTP request to a server which performs the calculations and then responds with the answers I need

Comment: @JoshBrass Actually that would be the best solution.

Comment: If you wanted to use a Database model, you could do it in Stored Procedures as well...

Answer (score 1):

I would look into creating a separate (WebAPI or WCF) service that has access to that file and knows how to serve up the public facing portions of it to your application.

So let's assume the file lives at `\\hrserver\C$\sensitive.dat`.  Your service has access to that file, but the client applications do not.  Your client applications access the service (`https://hrserverhelper/GetHrData`), which encapsulates the authentication/authorization to that file.  It then parses out the sensitive data (perhaps from the JSON you already are set up to create for that file), and passes the non-sensitive data to your client application.

If it turns out that **all** the data in the file is sensitive, then have your service provide operations to perform the calculations that your WinForms app performs currently.  For example, your WinForms app submits the inputs it wishes to perform to a WebMethod that knows how to perform those calculations with the sensitive data - the WebMethod spits out the results.

However, in this scenario, be aware that basic mathematical skills will likely be able to reverse engineer the "sensitive" data here.  If I submit 2 and get back 4, and I submit 3 and get back 6, I'll assume the "sensitive" number is 2.

Comment: When you say "Public Facing"...

If I assume that I have a calculation which uses inputs x, y, and z. Puts them into a box where some calculation is made using sensitive information to perform that calculation, and get outputs x1, y1 and z1. Would you consider the information which has been requested and used inside the box to be "public facing"? Because this is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: I was assuming that you had discrete portions of the file - some sensitive and some not.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: With regards to your final point, There are multiple different 'sensitive' values which would be used in a single calculation, so it wouldn't be possible to find out the exact figures.

Comment: I'm basically suggesting you recast your entire application as a Website (using ASP.NET or something similar), and have your WinForms app hook into APIs that ASP.NET site exposes.  That way you can avoid exposing the sensitive file.